# How to take a screenshot, crop it, and upload it as an image on a web form?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, screenshot, webpage-screenshot

How to take a screenshot, crop it, and upload it on a web form? 
Is this possible with using web technologies (js/jquery or some other).

**Or whether it can be glued with some other desktop software that does these sort of things?**

Comment: not the same thing. I want to take a screenshot of all desktop, not just DOM. Also I ask if a desktop software can be used to accomplish this

Comment: You'd likely need a tailor-made piece of software for every target OS for this. It's not possible from inside a web page.